# tfs checkout / checkin programmatically

Tags: tfs

I am building a VS2010 addin. This addin will work only for our custom project types and create a menu item that will copy the output assembly from the current solution to another solution. Both are under TFS control.

I have the following code:

```
var tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(address);
var version = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
var workspace = version.GetWorkspace(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName().ToString(), version.AuthorizedUser);

workspace.PendEdit(dest);
System.IO.File.Copy(source, dest, true);
```

Now I want to checkin the change. The problem is that I don't know how to select only that file I checked out just now? I have other pending changes in the same project and also in other projects. Will this checkin EVERYTHING I have checked out?
Can I be more selective?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically checkout a file in TFS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764883/programatically-checkout-a-file-in-tfs-2010)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scripting TFS Command Line for Get Latest Version, Check Out and Check in, programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762812/scripting-tfs-command-line-for-get-latest-version-check-out-and-check-in-progr/3763449#3763449)

Comment: @Betty - Not a duplicate of either of these. My question is not about command line, it's about C# code and my problem is not with the checkout, it's with the check in. Maybe you can read the question before commenting next time.

Comment: The second comment wasn't from me, but you're right, i'm not sure why i recommended that post when you clearly already had the checkout working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PendingChange[] pendingChange = workSpace.GetPendingChanges(dest);
workSpace.CheckIn(pendingChange, comments);
```

> **Workspace.GetPendingChanges Method (String)**
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139277(v=vs.100).aspx
>
> Parameters
>
> item:  The path, local or server, to the item that is being queried.

And

> **Workspace.CheckIn Method**
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.checkin(v=vs.100).aspx
>
> Parameters
>
> changes
>   The set of pending changes to check in. *If you do not specify this parameter, all changes in the workspace are checked in.*
>
> comment
>   The comment to be associated with this check-in. May be null.